# How to Fetch common column from multiple tables in Database?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

```
Greeting to all smart people around here !!
```

I have faced a weird interview question regarding SQL.

**Qn .**  `If I have 100 tables in Database. I want to fetch common records from Each table.`

For example, `location` is common field in 100 tables. I want to fetch `location` field from all the tables without mentioning each table name in my SQL query.

Is there any way to do it?

If any possibilities let me know...

Comment: No, not in SQL (at least nothing that would comply to standards, and work in more than one engine). Anyone who asks such a question in an interview needs to be whacked with a trout and taught about database design. Unless it's a trick question, and they wanted you to whack them with a trout.

Comment: Fine. If the same condition will work in `IBM DataStage tools`?

Comment: Never heard of it. If the question is database-specific, you should put it in tags, so knowledgeable people will notice it more easily.

Comment: If you say SQL only I would use SQL sysnonyms

Comment: you need to write a dynamic sql. iterate through tables and construct select statement to fetch location from those tables and store it in a temp table and return it.

Comment: Instead of all table names, can mention db_name to fetch common column from all tables??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend has found answer for my question..

To get common column from multiple tables,Use **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS** and common column name.

**Query :**
`select *from information_schema.columns where column_name='column name'`

Hope this will helpful !

Comment: but this will just give you information about specific column . How will you determine whether **specific column** is  a common column in all 100 tables ? I think you should post that answer and accept it ?

Comment: Nope, I've mentioned clearly in my question. Else i wouldn't have post this.

Answer (score 2):

get list of tables from db metadata, and then query with each:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet locationRs = null;
DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
while (rs.next()) {
    locationRs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT location from "+ rs.getString(3));
    System.out.println(locationRs.getString(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL Server you have INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table that contains the column names so you can use group by and having count some value you will get the column name after that you can use pivot to get the values of column names and carry on to it. You will get the ans.

For eg.

Select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS group BY COLUMN_NAME having count(COLUMN_NAME) > 2

By above query you will get the common column names

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for any Number of Tables in a DB :

```
select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  group by COLUMN_NAME having count(COLUMN_NAME)=(select count(*) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you already have connection and statemnt object's. Now try the below; it might work for you, if not make some adjustments with loops and conditions.   Also, you need to have two ResultSet Objects ex: rs1 and rs2.

---

DatabaseMetaData dbmd = con.getMetaData();
    String table[] = {"TABLE"} `;
        rs1 = dbmd.getTable(null, null, ".*" ,table);

```
while(rs1.next()){  
    String tableFrom = rs1.getString(3) ;
    rs2 =  dbmd.getColumns(null,null,tableFrom , ".*") ;  
     while(rs2.next()) { 

        String locColFrom = rs2.getString(3);  

        if(locColFrom .equalsIgnoreCase("location")) 
             stmt.executeQuery(select locColFrom from  tableFrom ) ;
        }
}
```

Here's an link to study [Oracle] (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))